# Why ES6 ComputedPropertyName does not work with this react js code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using `react 16.9.0`.

I'm trying to understand why the following fails to update `title` property of the component `state`:

```
this.setState({
  [formControlName]: event.target.value
});
```

But this does:

```
this.setState({
  title: event.target.value
});
```

Consider the component:

```
export class BookForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...props.book };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const formControlName = event.target.attributes['name'];

    // The following correctly logs "title"
    console.log(formControlName);

    // This does not work
    this.setState({
      [formControlName]: event.target.value
    });

    // This works, why?
    this.setState({
      title: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('Form submitted...');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label> Title:
          <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

`BookForm` is used like so:

```
<BookForm book={this.props.book}/>
```

Where a book may be something like this:

```
{
  author: "Marijn Haverbeke"
  description: "JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications."
 isbn: "9781593275846"
 pages: 472
 published: "2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z"
 publisher: "No Starch Press"
 subtitle: "A Modern Introduction to Programming"
 title: "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition"
 website: "http://eloquentjavascript.net/"
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: And also, please provide an error message as `This does not work` doesn't showing what went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console is tricking you a bit. The problem is here:

```
const formControlName = event.target.attributes['name'];
```

That gets the **Attribute node** for the `name` attribute, not its **value**. I guess when you log it, it shows you the attribute node in a way that looks like it's the string. The [`attributes` property](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attributes) is a [`NamedNodeMap`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#namednodemap) of the element's attributes. Indexing into it by name gives you the [`Attr` instance](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#attr). Converting an `Attr` instance to string (for me on Chrome) results in the string `"[object Attr]"`, so you're probably adding a property with that name to your state object. :-)

Instead, just use the reflected property, which gives you the string value:

```
const formControlName = event.target.name;
```

For completeness: You could also use `event.target.getAttribute("name")` or `event.target.attributes['name'].nodeValue`, but the simple and idiomatic way is to use the reflected property.